# Knockout MVC model binding in Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm using Knockout MVC. In my page I render several Partial View. In each partial view i pass a model, that is submodel for main. And i'm getting an error 'Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.' Here's some code.

main view

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model  UserPageViewModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
<div>
    @Html.Partial("Controls/_PagePanel", Model.PanelViewModel)
</div>
@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Page panel partial view

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model PagePanelViewModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
<div>
   <div>
      @foreach (var button in Model.Actions)
      {
       @ko.Html.Button(button.Id, button.ActionName, button.ControllerName, null, button.HtmlAttributes)
      }
      <a id="searchGridButton" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#searchPanel" href="#accordionfilterContainer">Advanced search</a>
  </div>
 @Html.Partial("Controls/_AdvancedSearch", Model.AdvancedSearch)
</div>
@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Advanced Search Partial View

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model  AdvancedSearchViewModel
@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}
<div id="accordionfilterContainer" class="accordion-body collapse">
    @using (ko.Html.Form(Model.ActionName, Model.ControllerName, null, new { id = "searchForm" }))
    {
        <div id="filterContainer" class="accordion-inner">
             @using (var items = ko.Foreach(m => m.SearchCriteria))
             {
                <div style="display: inline-block">
                    <span @items.Bind.Text(m => m.Id)></span>
                    <br />
                    @items.Html.TextBox(m => m.Value, null)
                </div>
             }
            <div style="display: inline-block">
                <button type="submit" class = "@Model.HtmlAttributes">Apply filters</button>
            </div>
      </div>
    }
</div>
@ko.Apply(Model)
```

Model

```
public class UserPageViewModel
{
    public List<User> Data { get; set; }

    public PagePanelViewModel PanelViewModel { get; set; }
}


public class PagePanelViewModel
{

    public IEnumerable<ButtonViewModel> FilterButtons { get; set; }

    public AdvancedSearchViewModel AdvancedSearch { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ButtonViewModel> Actions { get; set; }
}


public class AdvancedSearchViewModel 
{
    public IList<TextBoxViewModel> SearchCriteria { get; set; }
}
```

I understand, that the problem is in     @ko.Apply() string, but a don't understand why. Is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: @ko.Apply(Model) takes only one argument and i can't specify a DOM element to use as the root.

Comment: Apologies, I see that it's about knockout-mvc now. I've retracted my close vote, note a dupe after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. It's necessary to use     @ko.With() when rendering Partial view.

```
<div>
@using (var subModel = ko.With(m => m.PanelViewModel))
{
    @Html.Partial("Controls/_PagePanel", Model.PanelViewModel)
}
</div>
```

@ko.With() specifies the partial view what properties of submodel need to bind. And then need to delete all @ko.Apply(Model) except one in root page(main view).